# AndroidSutdio "bug" : Unable to view correctly a foreign UTF8 string in debug or android layout (Windows)

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, android-studio

I'm unable to view correctly my UTF8 string in AndroidSutdio debug or android layout.
below is my code :

```
       String test1 = "hélǐ";
```

Results is test1 = hÃ©lÇ�

test1 Looks similar to reading my UTF8 string with ANSI encoding in notepad++. However if I harcode it into the XML layout directly (instead of using Button.setHint() method) I can see hélǐ correctly.

UPDATE 1 : thanks Jon Skeet for pointing out test1.lenght() = 6 and not 4 thus is not a display issue.
UPDATE 2 : thanks Joop Eggen for pointing out that "h\u00e9l\u012d" return the correct answer
UPDATE 3 : I have copy paste my code to an equivalent android project on eclipse and it works fine. thus it must be AndroidStudio related issue.
UPDATE 4 : added a variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to force javac using that command but with no effect to the result.
UPDATE 5 : I installed AndroidStudio on ubuntu and copy paste my code and it run fine as well there. But how to fix it on AndroidStudio Windows? (as unfortunately I need to use windows)

Anyone ever faced that issue before? how to fix without using \u code
Thanks

note:

- I'm using AndroidStudio
- in my Javac and Android DX complier I added -encoding utf8
- in my AndroidStudio all files encodings are set to utf8 (and i can see utf8 in bottom right)
- Charset.defaultCharset() return utf8
- InputStreamReader.getEncoding() return utf8
- all my xml layout have an utf8 flag on the top
- Notepad++ read correctly my copy/paste "hélǐ" with utf8 encoding.

Comment: It sounds to me like however you're trying to pass the encoding to the compiler isn't working. Try `-encoding UTF-8` instead... although I'd expect it to fail completely if you gave it an incorrect encoding. You should *not* do any of `test2` to `test5`... "transcoding" strings is pretty much always a bad idea.

Comment: thanks. I tried changing to UTF-8 instead of utf8 but get same results. I prefer not use transcoding but right now i just want to make it works...

Comment: To remove the display part of it, you can just print out `test1.length()` - that should be 4, obviously. If you're sure your source code is UTF-8, you should probably just double-check *all* of the compiler settings, as that's where the problem probably is.

Comment: what a great idea. test1.length() return 6. confirming its not a display issue.

Comment: but now how do I check in all compiler settings in AndroidStudio ? I only can see those in Settings->Compiler and Settings-File Encodings which are all set to UTF-8.

Comment: Then it sounds like it *should* be okay... not being an Android developer, I'm afraid I can't give any more details :(

Comment: Hi Simon,
I have extractly this issue. If you get a solution for this. Please tell me. Thanks you so much. Im trying to solve this problem too.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @ThànhLê, i'm running my code in ubuntu AndroidStudio as a temporary solution until find a fix for the windows version.

Comment: @ThànhLê - fixed in latest version of AndroidStudio

Comment: @Simon, thanks you so much. I have note noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in latest version of AndroidStudio

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case for me? On version 2.2 just updated, and I still have problems. Added the compiler parameter as well.

Comment: 0.2.9 The problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

- Try `h\u00e9l\u012d` too. This removes the factor of java source encoding.
- Try writing the text to file:

  new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8")

Then the cause should become clearer.

As editor and compiler must use the same encoding, you seem to have done all thing possible for the rest. Especially checking with NotePad++ (- JEdit is possible too). One small point is IDE background compiling and and final compiling.

Also running is a console: the console could be erroneously use the operating system encoding.

All those `new String(...)` are superflous and erroneously. Do not use that here, as indeed one error could cancel an error between mismatched encoding of editor and compiler.

(In ISO-8859-1 `ĭ` (i-breve) is not available - hence test3.)

Comment: thanks. String test7 = "h\u00e9l\u012d" return the correct answer. But what do you mean by java source encoding ? is it javac? is it the .java file itself which is loaded with wrong encoding? I'm not sure whom is doing what and who's fault is it that \u00e9 works and not é.

Comment: It is editor encoding. As you did, with an editor capable to set differenct encodings, one can check this independent of the IDE. As you are doing (at least intend to), I use UTF-8, otherwise one cannot use international text like `ĉĝĥĵŝŭдруги`. The editor writes to some encoding on disk, and `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...` then would use an assumed encoding. Check again the settings (global, per project). The NetBeans IDE as of version 7.3 united the settings to one single.

Comment: Yes, I have copy paste my code to an equivalent android project on eclipse and it works fine. thus it must be AndroidStudio related issue. However I definitely set everywhere to use UTF-8 in AndroidStudio - I spent hours to check everywhere. And when i open the java file with notepad++ i can confirme its UTF-8. I don't seems to be able to see the effective javac command though.

Comment: Maybe a command line parameter might help `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. Good luck.

Comment: thanks. I added an variable environment which said to force javac using that parameters. JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. unfortunatly no much change.

Answer (score 1):

My case was exactly the same as Simon (I am using Android Studio for Mac 0.2.2)

I solved the problem by editing the **build.gradle** file under the /src folder, adding these lines:

```
tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

It worked for me. Hope it helps somebody with the same problem.

Comment: Doesn't work with Android Studio 0.8. It says that Compile is deprecated.